# What is a Thread-pool?

Tags: c, pthreads, threadpool

What is the concept of implementing Thread-pool (in C with help from pthreads)?
how can a thread be assigned to execute from the thread pool ?

Answer (score 11):

A thread-pool is a collection of a fixed number of threads which are created on application startup. The threads then sit waiting for requests to come to them, typically via a queue controlled by a semaphore. When a request is made, and there is at least one thread waiting, the thread is woken up, services the request, and goes back to waiting on the semaphore. If no threads are available, requests queue up until one is.

Thread-pools are a generally more efficient way of managing resources than simply starting a new thread for every request. However, some architectures allow new threads to be created and added to the pool as the application runs, depending on request loading.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify something in previous answers:

The reason that instantiating more and more threads leads to inefficiency is *context switching time*.  The OS periodically switches one thread for another on the processor.  This involves saving one thread's state and loading another thread's state from memory, so it takes non-negligible time, N ms, per context switch.

For example, if you have 10 threads, the context switching takex 10*N ms.  If you have 1000 threads, it's 1000*N ms.  As the number of concurrent threads increases, eventually the context switching begins to overwhelm any efficiencies derived from multithreading.  Your application has a sweet spot in terms of the best number of threads.  Once you determine this sweet number by experimentation, you can set your thread pool max size to that number of threads, thereby obtaining maximum efficiency from multithreading.

Comment: It's unlikely that it would take even as much as 1 ms to context switch, generally these are more along the lines of us. Everything else is very nice though.

Comment: who said N was an integer and who said it was >= 1?

Comment: Using the units ms suggests that the time will be on the order of ms. I believe that most people reading your answer would not think that the context switching time was around say 1 us.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to anon's answer I'd like to mention that there are Fixed thread pools which have fixed numbers of thread running in them; Cached thread pools which can dynamically grow and then shrink when no work is available; Dynamic thread pools can also be bound by maximum number of threads and/or maximum length of the work queue. I don't think there is actually a set terminology for this kind of stuff and one rarely encounters non-fixed TPs written in C but at least one should know that fixed TP is not the only kind out there.